# Error not getting caught

Tags: magento-1.9, error, error-log

I am trying to write orders. But something is wrong there. Unfortunately I don't know what because

```
    $transaction->addObject($order);
    $transaction->addCommitCallback(array($order, 'place'));
    $transaction->addCommitCallback(array($order, 'save'));
    try {
      $transaction->save();
    } catch(Exception $e) {
      Mage::log($e);
    }
```

in that code the $transaction-save() is not logging any error. When I reach `$transaction->save();` the script stops and all next steps are not getting called. I want that this error is getting logged somewhere, so that I know what I did wrong.

Comment: Did you check Apache's log?

Comment: thanks. I can could find an error there `[Thu Oct 22 15:06:30.438507 2015] [:error] [pid 3396] [client 127.0.0.1:45301] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getMethodInstance() on a non-object in /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Model/Observer.php on line 46, referer: http://127.0.0.1/magento/index.php/checkout/onepage/`

Comment: Are you sure you're using an existing payment method?